# Apache htaccess RewriteRule not working with specific word

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 RewriteRule.

```
1.RewriteRule ^page/([^\.]*)/ page.php?_path=page_detail&id=$1 [QSA,L]

2.RewriteRule ^page2/([^\.]*)/ page.php?_path=page_detail&id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

When I test with the URL `localhost/page2/1/about`.

I have got `print_r($_GET)` and it redirects the complete URL `page.php?_path=page_detail&id=1`

---

When I test with the URL `localhost/page/1/about`.

Its not working. I didnt get `print_r($_GET)`. But it only shows blank page.

---

I don't understand why if I use the word "page" it won't work.

Comment: Having a same problem with word "academy"

Answer (score 0):

If its sensitive to the names, it may be that ur htaccess is only accepting names of folders... Meaning what if page2 or page1 at the beginning would work only if a folder has that name...
Im tryna check a final solution  but u may stick to using names of folders